# Xcode 15.1 & iOS 17.2: SwiftData ModelContext Delete: It's only possible to delete the data after it has been inserted for about 30 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, ios17

I'm a newbie in working with SwiftData and I hope for your help in solving the below issue :")

It's about deleting the objects into a Model by ModelContext.delete(). It's only possible to delete the data after it has been inserted for about 30 seconds.

Just run the source code below, tap on "Add" button to add some samples, and then tap on "Delete" button right away. At this time, Delete action doesn't work. You have to wait about 30 seconds, then tap on "Delete" button, it will work - the sample data are deleted properly.

I tested this issue on Xcode 15.1 beta (15C5042i) and found that:

- This issue always **happens** on Preview w/ iOS 17 or iOS 17.2.
- This issue **doesn't happen** on Simulator w/ iOS 17 BUT it **happens** on Simulator w/ iOS 17.2

I think this issue could be caused by ModelContext AutoSave, it only actually saves the data after the data have been inserted for about 30 seconds, during this delay time, the modelContext.delete() function doesn't work.

[Issue's video demo on youtube](https://youtu.be/_v7lKRVrrJU)

Full source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/projectxmaker/swiftdataautosavedelay.git)

Bike.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model class Bike {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

TestApp.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            BikeListView()
        }
        .modelContainer(for: Bike.self)
    }
}
```

BikeListView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct BikeListView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var bikes: [Bike]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 30) {
                Button {
                    addSamples()
                } label: {
                    Text("Add")
                }
                
                Button {
                    deleteSamples()
                } label: {
                    Text("Delete")
                }
            }
            
            List {
                ForEach(bikes) { eachBike in
                    Text(eachBike.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addSamples() {
        let bikeOne = Bike(name: "One")
        let bikeTwo = Bike(name: "Two")
        
        modelContext.insert(bikeOne)
        modelContext.insert(bikeTwo)
    }
    
    func deleteSamples() {
        try? modelContext.delete(model: Bike.self)
    }
}

#Preview {
    do {
        let modelConfig = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)
        let modelContainer = try ModelContainer(for: Bike.self, configurations: modelConfig)
        return BikeListView()            .modelContainer(modelContainer)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Content View's Preview")
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading and I'm looking forward to your help.

Comment: Not sure if it is related but you want your preview to only store data in memory, `ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)`

Comment: Hi @JoakimDanielson, I've set isStoredInMemoryOnly to true and tested on Xcode 15.0 + iOS 17.0 and Xcode 15.1 + iOS 17.2, it doesn't work, the issue still happens :(

Comment: I tried to reproduce this and I got a similar although not the exact same result as you. But by looking at the core data logs and also viewing the table in an sql client I can clearly see that it is a long delay between when two new rows appear in the UI and when they have been inserted into the sql table.

Comment: The workaround for now is to explicitly call save() after the insert so add `try modelContext.save()` at the end of the addSamples function. I think you should either file a bug report with Apple or wait and see if it gets resolved when iOS 17.2 is released.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for your recommendation. I'm current using iOS 17.2 and use modelContext.save() as the workaround for this issue. I also hope it will be fixed in upcoming iOS versions.